# calling code behind method using $http- angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. Recently I am going through a solution which uses angularjs to call a code behind method:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/provisioning/templates/getAvailableTemplates',
        headers: { 'accept': 'application/json'   }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config){})
          .error(function (data, status) {});
```

and code behind method is like this:

```
[Route("api/provisioning/templates/getAvailableTemplates")]
[WebAPIContextFilter]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetSiteTemplates()
{

}
```

Could anyone please explain me the working of this. I tried to replicate this in my new application, but no luck.

Comment: what is the issue? error? any response?

Comment: code is not calling the code behind method :(

Comment: Try to change your URL to full URL rather than relative URL. Something like url: 'http://localhost:49325/api/provisioning/templates/getAvailableTemplates'. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $http({ method: "GET", url: root + "Admin/content/GetTabs" });
```

$scope.GetTabs= function () {

```
        api.GetTabs().success(function (res) {

            $scope.MetaInfoList = res;
        })
    }
```